# Read Facebook Ads using Ad account ID not owned by me

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

My Application has both **ads_management** and **ads_read** permissions. I need to get campaigns, adssets & ads under an ad account, and I don't have any permission on.

My question is, if user with admin privilege on ad account/page granted my app to read page ads using read_ads permission, I will be able to get ads under this specific ad account? And if no, how I can get ad set insights for ads on pages their owners grants my app permission to read their ads?